# Specific examples of signalling pathway using logical 'OR' and 'AND'?

Tags: cell-biology, literature, cell-signaling

I have read [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/cell-signaling/mechanisms-of-cell-signaling/a/intracellular-signal-transduction) that 
"**signals from two different pathways may be needed to activate a response, which is like a logical "AND." Alternatively, either of two pathways may trigger the same response, which is like a logical "OR."**
But no example is mentioned. I want to know some specific examples in which cell signalling uses logical OR and Logical AND. Any references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are thousands of examples, here I list just a few.

1) Macrophage activation. This is a complex case with many proteins acting as AND/OR. The following paper depicts a nice scheme that helps to understand the circuit.

https://bmcsystbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1752-0509-2-36

2) The Lac operon that follows the logic:

```
if low_glucose AND lactose:
    express(lac_genes)

if (high_glucose OR low_glucose) AND no_lacotse:
    inhibit(lac_genes)

if high_glucose AND lacotse:
    express_at_low_level(lac_genes)
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lac_operon

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_biological_circuit

3) Phosphorylation and ubiquitination pathways. For example,

> ... proteins primed through phosphorylation by one protein
>   kinase are often phosphorylated processively on the N-terminal side of
>   the priming phosphate by GSK3 at a series of Ser/Thr spaced by three
>   residues, with the cluster of phosphates regulating protein activity
>   **(e.g., glycogen synthase, β-catenin)**. If the two sites are
>   phosphorylated by different protein kinases, then this can in
>   principle provide a logical **AND** gate in a downstream response.

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1097276507007988

4) Neurotransmitter signaling pathways.
Figure 2 of the following paper

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022519306003675

describes the boolean logic underlining the signaling pathway

> Tyrosine hydroxylase activates itself in this model.
>   There is an “AND NOT” gate between
>   tyrosine hydroxylase and COMT to activate dopamine as
>   tyrosine hydroxylase and not COMT activates dopamine...
>
> ...adenylate cyclase is activated by dopamine
>   receptor 1 and not by dopamine receptor 2, which has been
>   represented by the “AND NOT” gate between the input nodes.
>
> ...
>
> DARPP32, is activated by protein kinase A, and
>   not by calcineurin, therefore protein kinase A “AND NOT”
>   calcineurin activates DARPP32.
>
> DARPP32 inhibits protein phosphatase1, which is
>   represented by the “NOT” gate from DARPP32 for protein
>   phosphatase1.
>   ...
>   The activation of glutamate receptor, needs the presence of both
>   protein kinase A and the ligand, glutamate therefore, a
>   “AND” gate between protein kinase A and glutamate, “AND NOT”
>   protein phosphatase 1. ...

[Here the link](http://bioinformatics.ac.cn/synbiolgdb/) to a database of natural and artificial biological logic gates and [here the article](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep08090) presenting the database

To conclude, I would like to highlight [this work](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/340/6132/599.full) on the engineering of a biological transistor.

Comment: In the paper [link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3632399/)I find this **statement TSC2 can be directly phosphorylated by both ERK and ERK-activated ribosomal protein S6 kinase (RSK) on S664 and S1798, respectively, as well as by AKT (on S939 and T1362.** in figure 4. Can you please advise if this is an example of **OR** where TSC2 can be phosphorylated either by RSK and ERK or by AKT. In case if it is not do you know any such logical signalling in cancer metabolism.

Comment: If you consider phosphorylation in general, it is an OR. But since you get different residues phosphorylated by different enzymes then I would rather consider them separately. What is the output you are looking for in this case?

Comment: If my 1 at output means to phosphorylate and 0 means not to phosphorylate then can it be considered as an OR Boolean logic?

Comment: Yes, if you consider "just phosphorylation" then yes, it's an OR. Indeed you will have 1 as output as long at least one among ERK, RSK and AKT, are active.